# Unable to export .csv file in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, csv, internet-explorer, download

I'm trying to export my data as CSV file. I wrote below code, that is working fine in Firefox/Chrome but not in IE. I need to make work in IE8/9/10 versions. Thanks in advance.

JS code:

```
var CSVgen = function (CSV, ReportName) {
  //Generate a file name if empty is replace by _.
  var fileName = ReportName.replace(/ /g,"_");
  //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
  var uri = 'data:text/csv;Content-Type:application/octet-stream;Content-Disposition: attachment;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
  //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
  var link = document.createElement("a");    
  link.href = uri;
  //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
  link.style = "visibility:hidden";
  link.download = fileName + ".csv";
  //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

And i tried below ways also:

> var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

and

> var uri = 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream;Content-Disposition:
>   attachment;' + escape(CSV);

But no luck. I'm getting below error page in IE:

```
The webpage cannot be displayed

Most likely cause:
  •Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.

What you can try:
  Search online for a program you can use to view this web content.   
  Retype the address.  
  Go back to the previous page.
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Download attribute on A tag not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042847/data-uri-file-download-in-interent-explorer